# Should I use present tense or past tense?

Tags: verbs, tenses

Should I use present tense (spans) or past tense (spanned) in the following example?

"Dr X's service in providing data to the community {spans | spanned} across mission X (2003), mission Y (2008-present), and mission Z (2015-present)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to suggest that Dr. X is still providing data? In that case 
use the present perfect progressive, to express an action that began in the past and which is still ongoing:

> He has been singing at church on Sundays for years.

In a situation like this, neither the simple present nor the simple past works:

> He sings at church on Sundays for years (or since 2001)

is non-sensical, and

> He sang at church since 2003 to the present

indicates that, as of today, his singing days are over.

But I think the verb choice you've made here is not the best. "Span" means to bridge or to cross, as in "an arch spanned the stream." So, *span across* is redundant, and the sentence is otherwise not idiomatic, to my ear at least. I would recast the entire thing:

> Dr X has been providing data to the community since 2003, beginning
>   with mission X and extending through mission Y (2008-present) and
>   mission Z (2015-present)

Answer (score 0):

The subject here is "the span of Dr X's service", which is a single thing.  If that span includes the present day, then the span is **current**, ie in the present, and so you should say "spans".

Also, i think it's better to say "spans Mission X (2003)... etc" rather than "spans across": both "span" and "across" are to do with covering an area, so to use both is redundant.

Comment: Thank you Max, I really appreciate your prompt assistance.  I agree with you the phase "span across" has redundant meaning.